# django-python how to convert text to pdf

Tags: python, django, pdf

I am doing a project in *python-django,* i would like to know whether there is any built-in library or something like that, that can convert text to pdf. Something similar to pyTeaser for converting image to text

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several options out there:

- [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/) (suggested by [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/))
- [PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html) (or +[slate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slate) wrapper)
- [pdfrw](https://code.google.com/p/pdfrw/)
- [xhtml2pdf](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/)
- [pyfpdf](https://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/) (no changes since august, 2012)
- [pyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/) (not maintained)

Also take a look at:

- [Python PDF library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413441/python-pdf-library)
- [Outputting PDFs with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/)
- [Open Source PDF Libraries in Python](http://pythonsource.com/open-source/pdf-libraries)
- [Generating PDFs with Django](http://agiliq.com/blog/2008/10/generating-pdfs-with-django/)
- [Django, ReportLab PDF Generation attached to an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378713/django-reportlab-pdf-generation-attached-to-an-email)
- [A Simple Step-by-Step Reportlab Tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/)
- [Django output pdf using reportlab](http://www.thusjanthan.com/node/62)

Hope that helps.

Comment: First of all , thanks for the suggestions. I tried reportlab as per your suggestion. But can i use it in my project. ? When i read the reportlab documentation, it says it will convert documents written in RML (Report Markup Language ) to PDF.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, reportlab is the first option to try (and may be the last one too), see [an example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/) in django docs.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [django-webodt](https://github.com/NetAngels/django-webodt) for a few days now to convert OpenOffice template (.odt) dynamically into PDF filling placeholders with database models.

test.odt could be...

> Hello {{ first_name }}

```
import webodt
template = webodt.ODFTemplate('test.odt')
context = dict(first_name="Mary")
document = template.render(Context(context))
from webodt.converters import converter
conv = converter()
pdf = conv.convert(document, format='pdf')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... But when i run the first line, ie "import webod" , it shows an error - 'import error: No module named 1xml. What to do ? I installed django-webodt from the link you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Download and try [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/532908-text-to-pdf-converter-rewrite/download/1/). The author wrote this:

> PyText2Pdf  makes a 7-bit clean PDF file from any input file.
>
> It reads from a named file, and writes the PDF file to a file
>   specified by the user, otherwise to a file with '.pdf' appended to the
>   input file.

You could run it as stated below:

```
text2pdf.py rfc_3917.txt -S "Netflow RFC" -A "Quittek, et al." -K netflow,rfc,networking,ipfix -R "[Page\s+\d+]"
```

But check inside the script for more details.

A link to its usage in Django is [here](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1778/) but partly outdated because the older script was used. The link I provided here is the newer one.